# What is the word for a group of genes inherited together?

Tags: genetics, molecular-genetics, gene

I know the words haplotype and haplogroup, as well as genetic linkage, but...

I recently came across a new phrase describing genes which tend to be inherited as a group, and wrote it down, but now cannot find it...

Also, is there a word or phrase for genes which are expressed together?

Comment: "inherited together" (e.g. in linkage) or "expressed together" (e.g. coexpressed)? These are two different situations

Comment: @FabioMarroni — He wrote inherited. He is talking about genetic linkage. Why don’t you believe he means what he says? He asks a second question about expression, which is against the rules and also unclear because he doesn’t say whether he’s talking about eukaryotes and prokaryotes. That affects whether the one answer so far to that question is correct or not.

Comment: @David, you're right, I didn't understand that the second question was a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are referring to [operon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operon)?

> In genetics, an operon is a functioning unit of DNA containing a cluster of genes under the control of a single promoter. The genes are transcribed together into an mRNA strand and either translated together in the cytoplasm, or undergo splicing to create monocistronic mRNAs that are translated separately, i.e. several strands of mRNA that each encode a single gene product.

There is also a term called [supergene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supergene) which is in a way a less strict grouping, suggesting close genetic linkage and possible functional relationship.